# How to use `.kind()` on my custom errors?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm wondering how I can do some pattern-matching on my custom errors, to have a specific behaviour for a few errors and a generic behaviour for the others.

I have the following custom error, defined using `thiserror` as it seems to be the latest recommended crate for custom errors in July 2020.

```
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError{
    #[error("Error while building the query")]
    Builder(#[source] hyper::http::Error),

    #[error("Generic error")]
    Fuck,
    
    #[error("Not OK HTTP response code")]
    NotOK,
    
    #[error("Request error")]
    Request(#[source] hyper::Error),
}
```

```
pub async fn do_http_stuff() -> Result<Vec<u8>, MyError> {
   ...
}
```

And:

```
    match do_http_stuff().await {
      Ok(data) => ...,
      Err(error) => match error.kind() {
        MyError::NotOK => {
          println!("not ok");
        },
        _ => {
          println!("{}", error.to_string());
        },
      },
    },
```

But `.kind()` is not implemented. When I search about how to manage errors in rust, kind is often in the examples. What kind of incantations should I do to have this `.kind()` method or something equivalent in my project too ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you're referring to the `std::io::Error:kind` method. It's specifically for IO errors. Because it needs to be able to represent OS errors, `io::Error` isn't defined as an enum, and we can't match on it. The `kind` method allows us to get an `ErrorKind` representing the generic cause of the error in a platform independent way.

This workaround is completely unnecessary in a normal Rust library, as all of your error cases can be expressed simply (as the variants of your `enum`). All you need to do is match on the `error` value directly